# Process a list in a Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I created a DataFrame `neighbours` using `sim_measure_i` which is also a DataFrame.

```
neighbours= sim_measure_i.apply(lambda s: s.nlargest(k).index.tolist(), axis =1)
```

`neighbours` looks like this:

```
1500                       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1501                       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1502                       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1503     [7230, 12951, 13783, 8000, 18077]
1504                     [1, 3, 6, 27, 47]
```

The second column here has lists - I want to iterate over this DataFrame and work on the list such that I can read each element in the list - say 7230 and lookup a score for 7230 in another DataFrameI have which contains (id, score).

I would then like to add a column to this DataFrame such that it looks like

```
test_case_id               nbr_list             scores             
1500                       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]        [+1, -1, -1, +1, -1]
1501                       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]        [+1, +1, +1, -1, -1]
1502                       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]        [+1, +1, +1, -1, -1]
1503     [7230, 12951, 13783, 8000, 18077]        [+1, +1, +1, -1, -1]
1504                     [1, 3, 6, 27, 47]        [+1, +1, +1, -1, -1]
```

Edit: I've written a method `get_scores()`

```
def get_scores(list_of_neighbours):
    score_matrix = []
    for x, val in enumerate(list_of_neighbours):
        score_matrix.append(df.iloc[val].score)
    return score_matrix
```

When I try to use `lambda` on each of `nbr_list`, I get this error:

```
TypeError: ("cannot do positional indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'> with these indexers [0] of <type 'str'>", u'occurred at index 1500')
```

The code causing this issue:

```
def nearest_neighbours(similarity_matrix, k):
    neighbours = pd.DataFrame(similarity_matrix.apply(lambda s: s.nlargest(k).index.tolist(), axis =1))
    neighbours = neighbours.rename(columns={0 : 'nbr_list'})

    nbr_scores = neighbours.apply(lambda l: get_scores(l.nbr_list), axis=1)

    print neighbours
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a nested loop:

```
for i in range(neighbours.shape[0]): #iterate over each row
    for j in range(len(neighbours['neighbours_lists'].iloc[i])): #iterate over each element of the list
        a = neighbours['neighbours_lists'].iloc[i][j] #access the element of the list index j in cell location of row i
```

where `i` is the outer loop variable which iterates over each row and `j` is the inner loop variable which iterates over the length of the list inside each cell.

Answer (score 1):

Original Data Frame:

```
In [68]: df
Out[68]: 
   test_case_id                   neighbours_lists
0          1500                    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1          1501                    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
2          1502                    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
3          1503  [7230, 12951, 13783, 8000, 18077]
4          1504                  [1, 3, 6, 27, 47]
```

Custom function which takes id and list and does some computation to evaluate score:

```
In [69]: def g(_id, nbs):
    ...:     return ['-1' if (_id + 1) % (nb + 1) else '+1' for nb in nbs]
    ...:
```

[Apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) custom function to all rows of original data frame:

```
In [70]: scores = df.apply(lambda x: g(x.test_case_id, x.neighbours_lists), axis=1)
```

[Convert](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) the scores series to a data frame and [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) it with the original data frame:

```
In [71]: df = pd.concat([df, scores.to_frame(name='scores')], 1)

In [72]: df
Out[72]: 
   test_case_id                   neighbours_lists                scores
0          1500                    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [+1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
1          1501                    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [+1, +1, -1, -1, -1]
2          1502                    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [+1, -1, +1, -1, -1]
3          1503  [7230, 12951, 13783, 8000, 18077]  [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
4          1504                  [1, 3, 6, 27, 47]  [-1, -1, +1, -1, -1]
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked with slight modifications for my case.

Answer (score 1):

Say you start with `neighbors` looking like this.

```
In [87]: neighbors = pd.DataFrame({'neighbors_list': [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]})

In [88]: neighbors
Out[88]: 
    neighbors_list
0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You didn't specify exactly how the other DataFrame (containing the id-score pairs looks), so here is an approximation.

```
In [89]: id_score = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'score': [1, -1, -1, 1, -1]})

In [90]: id_score
Out[90]: 
   id  score
0   0      1
1   1     -1
2   2     -1
3   3      1
4   4     -1
```

You can convert this to a dictionary:

```
In [91]: d = id_score.set_index('id')['score'].to_dict()
```

And then `apply`:

```
In [92]: neighbors.neighbors_list.apply(lambda l: [d[e] for e in l])
Out[92]: 
0    [1, -1, -1, 1, -1]
1    [1, -1, -1, 1, -1]
Name: neighbors_list, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to do it without a dict but I learned another method through your answer.